# Программно изменить переменную в ресурсах

Tags: android

В Android Studio есть папка **values**, в ней файл **strings.xml**, там есть переменная:

```
<string name="nav_header_title">Имя</string>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как программно её можно изменить из-какого нибудь Activity с помощью функции?

```
public void regSubmit(View v) {
 // какой-то код на изменение этой переменной
}
```

Comment: для чего вам менять значение переменной в ресурсах?

Comment: вы лучше напишите, что вы хотите в результате.

Comment: Вам лучше завести для этого дела другую переменную и устанавливать вместо замены ее. и результат к примеру сохранять в preference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программно никак. Вы должны понимать что в рантайме вы не сможете менять строки которые предоставлены как ресурсы. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programmatically) вопрос по вашей тематике. Но вы можете использовать такую штуку как `placeholder`. Суть в том что по умолчанию у вас при старте приложения ВАМИ будет устанавливаться значение для этого строкового ресурса одно, а потом вы сможете его при надобности менять. Вот например как можно использовать ресурсы с `placeholder`:

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

и дальше вы берете из ресурса строку и устанавливаете значение:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
```

Суть в том что вы можете устанавливать не только строку но и число. [Вот](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) есть документация по интересующей вас теме. Вот еще пример:

```
<plurals name="welcome_messages">
    <item quantity="one">Hello, %1$s! You have a new message.</item>
    <item quantity="other">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</item>
</plurals>
```

и вот в активности пишем так:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.welcome_messages, mailCount, username, mailCount);
```

[вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals) документация. Суть я думаю уже понятна :) Если  что-то не получится - пишите, постараемся помочь :)